# sitecore programmatically change imagefield datasource

Tags: sitecore

I need image field source of a product item to change depending on the folder path I am creating a product item under when creating the item in content or page editor.

If I am creating a product under `/home/bicycles`, I need the product item image field to auto change to `/sitecore/media library/Images/bicycles`

If I am creating a product under `/home/cars`, I need the product item image field to auto change to `/sitecore/media library/Images/cars`

If I am creating a product under `/home/scooters`, I need the product item image field to auto change to `/sitecore/media library/Images/scooters`

The default setting for that image field source in the datatemplate is `/sitecore/media library/Images/bicycles`

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: It seems I need to hook into the RenderField pipeline and based on the part, change the source for the image field. How do I go about doing that? I am a Sitecore newbiee :)

Comment: Is this a real business requirement?  If, for example, `bicycles`, `cars`, and `scooters` were different departments with different authors you might be able to achieve this in a way using Sitecore Permissions to only give them access to certain parts of the Media Library.  If you really need to write code, you could create a custom field type that extends the `Image` field... then you would have the necessary hook to tweak the datasource.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is a business requirement but they are not separate departments, there are about 250 authors and about 400 folders with subfolders under the media library, it will save a lot of headache if the image field can just open its related folder path under the media library for media upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a custom Content Editor field that extends the default image field type.

Start by creating a class that inherits from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image`. Then override the `OnPreRender` method to determine and set the `Source` property of the image field based on your location criteria/requirements.

See comments in the code below for more information.

```
public class ContextAwareImageField : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ItemID proprety is set by the Content Editor via reflection
    /// </summary> 
    public string ItemID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override the OnPreRender method. 
    /// The base OnPreRender method assigns a value to the Source viewstate property and we need to overwrite it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        Source = GetSource();
    }

    protected virtual string GetSource()
    {
        //retrieve and return the computed source value if it has already been set
        var contextSource = GetViewStateString("ContextSource");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contextSource))
            return contextSource;

        //retrieve the context item (the item containing the image field)
        var contextItem = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(ItemID);
        if (contextItem == null)
            return string.Empty;

        //determine the source to be used by the media browser
        //in this case we're just checking based on parent path, but any logic could be inserted
        contextSource = "/sitecore/media library/Images";
        switch (contextItem.Parent.Paths.FullPath.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "/sitecore/content/home/bicycles":
                contextSource = "/sitecore/media library/Images/Bicycles";
                break;
            case "/sitecore/content/home/cars":
                contextSource = "/sitecore/media library/Images/Cars";
                break;
            case "/sitecore/content/home/scooters":
                contextSource = "/sitecore/media library/Images/Scooters";
                break;
        }

        //store the computed source value in view bag for later retrieval
        SetViewStateString("ContextSource", contextSource);

        //return the computed source value
        return contextSource;
    }
}
```

Next, perform the following steps:

- Login to the Sitecore desktop with administrator rights and use the database icon in the lower right to switch to the **Core** database.
- In the **Core** database, open the **Content Editor** then navigate to `/sitecore/system/Field Types/Simple Types`. There you will find an item representing the **Image** field type.
- Duplicate the **Image** field type item and rename the duplicated item to something relevant (e.g. **Context Aware Image**).
- Edit the duplicated item

  - In the **Assembly** field, provide the name of the assembly file containing your custom image field class (e.g. `MyClient.MySite.dll`)
  - In the **Class** field, provide the name of the custom image field class, including the namespace (e.g. `MyClient.MySite.CustomFields.ContextAwareImageField`)
- Delete the value in the **Control** field
- Save your changes
- Switch back to the **Master** database.
- Open the **Content Editor**, then navigate to a template that should contain your new image field.
- Either create a new field in the template and choose your new custom field type in the **Type** dropdown. Or, change the **Type** for an existing image field.
- Save your template changes.
- In the content tree, navigate to an item based on the template above and click the **Browse** button for the contained image field. The media browser dialog should default to the source location specified by the logic in your custom field.

  - **Note**: if you are using a version of Sitecore that contains a SPEAK-based media browser dialog, you will have to switch to **Tree View** in the dialog (icon in the upper right) in order to see the source location specified by your custom field.

Comment: While this "solves" the issue it is a horrid way to do it. Sitecore has templates with multiple inheritance. You need to think OO for this. A bicycle, a car and a scooter surely have similar properties but they're not the same! Thus you can create an abstract base class vehicle which covers these and inherit from there to add your specific properties. Sitecore works the same way but with templates. Would you be happy if you buy a car and I give you a scooter instead?